# event in form1 when you Dispose DailogForm2 VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I run form1 then I call form2 as Showdailog

```
 Form2.ShowDialog()
```

after finish work in form2 ,I run Me.Dispose()
form2 Is Dispose and form1 shown again , I need to do some action before form1 active ..
How can I do That ?

Comment: Use the simple  [Form.Closing()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is right, but when i need to do that, i do like this:

Sub 
    form2.showdialog() 
    [ 
      things to do after the form 2 closing 
    ] 
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, just use `Form2_FormClosing`

```
Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

  If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to close this form?", "Confirm", _
MessageBoxStyle.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

    'Do Stuff

  Else
   e.Cancel = True
  End If
End Sub
```